# Unable to Access the Jenkins from Browser(Windows)

Tags: jenkins, browser, vagrant, centos7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLXUB.png)I have created the centos(Centos 7) server on Virtual Box(on Windows 10 machine) through the Vagrant image. But I am unable to access the Jenkins UI from the browser(Chrome, Edge, Mozilla) through http://localhost:8080(I have tried 8081 as well) I searched almost 100+ links but did not find any solution related to this but seen many questions asking the same problem.

Details:

1. Virtual Box installed on Windows 10 and on top of Virtual Box I clone Vagrant Centos Image to installed Jenkins.
2. Java 11 installed on Windows 10 and same on Centos server.
3. Disable firewall of Centos machine as well of Windows 10

Solution be highly appreciated!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGfJY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your Vagrantfile, but have you checked the settings of your VM's network interface?

The URL you're using http://localhost:8080 connects to your actual host. This should work inside the CentOS VM and if you're using NAT. Otherwise you'll have to replace localhost with your VM's IP address.